# Android の WebView を回転させた時にモーダルウィンドウが消える

Tags: android, webview

はじめまして。
Android の `WebView` を使ったアプリの開発をしています。

`WebView` にて、モーダルウィンドウを表示した状態で `WebView` を回転させると、
モーダルウィンドウが消えてしまいます。

たとえば、この「[モーダルウィンドウのデモ](http://syncer.jp/_demo/javascript/jquery-modal-window/modal.html)」のモーダルウィンドウを Android の `WebView` で表示した状態で、 Android を回転させるとモーダルが消えます。

Google Chrome や Firefox などの既存のブラウザアプリではこれが消えずに残るため、なにか方法があると思うのですがそれが分かりません。

`WebView` の回転時にリロードしないように、 `AndroidManifest.xml` に以下の記述を加えたり、

```xml
<application
...
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
/>
```

`MainActivity` 内で `onSavedInstance` を使って値を保存したり、

```java
WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        webView.loadUrl("http://syncer.jp/_demo/javascript/jquery-modal-window/modal.html");
    }

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

いろいろと試してみたのですが、どうにも解決できません。
この問題の解決策をご存知の方、お力添えをよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

すみません。自己解決しました。

AndroidManifest.xmlに書いていたconfigChangesをapplicationタグではなくactivityタグに移動させたら普通に動きました。。。
お騒がせして申し訳ないです。

ちなみに、ちゃんと動いたコードはGithubにて公開していますので同じ悩みに陥った方はご参照くださいませ。
https://github.com/litmon/WebView_Sample

Comment: 個人的に消える理由が気になっていた質問だったので、解決してよかったと思っています。ドキュメントを見てみると、確かに [`<application>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)要素は、`configChanges` を持てず、[`<activity>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)は持てるようです。これはエラーが出ないのが痛い。しかしレポジトリ付きとか贅沢な回答ですね。

Comment: 回答を承認してはいかがですか？とても良い回答だと思いますので。